# push from custom cell nib to viewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, custom-cell, xcode7.1

I'm using a `UITableViewController` as Source, the destination is a UIViewController with a UITableView.

I want to `push from (a) tableViewCell (in a custom cell of a tableview in .xib) to (b) viewController` . The custom cell is specified in a .xib file. I have tried control drag to create segue but I'm not able to do that.

How can I c push from the customCell to the UIViewController?
I have tried

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` `{
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")`

```
    let destination = FestsViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)}
```

I am getting black background with no labels .
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Segues is available only in a storyboards. 
You have to do your navigation manually in 
`-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //some checks 
    //...

    UIViewController *destinationVC = //init it with nib or instantiate from storyboard   
    //pass some parameters if you need
    //e.g.
    //destinationVC.prop1 = someValue; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I have tried but I'm getting black background you can see I have attached the screenshot above also the tab menu is not disappearing .

Comment: rename you ViewController's xib filename to 'FestsViewController' and change that line to:
    `let destination = FestsViewController(nibName: "FestsViewController", bundle: nil)`

Comment: It is crashing  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle `

Comment: Are you sure that you have that nib at all?

Comment: I got  a customCell.xib

Comment: You've created your view controller with xib or in a storyboard?

Comment: i have created a customCell with xib and viewController in storyboard

Comment: then give a StoryboardID to your view controller (say "festVC") from that storyboard, and instantiate it from the code. 
`let destination = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(@"festVC") as FestsViewController`